# SEVERE [http-nio2-8444-exec-242] java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

We have a web portal here developed by a 3rd party team that we no longer work with unfortunately. This web portal is used to make calls to our Active Directory via LDAP to authenticate users so they can requests activation keys for their mobile devices.

We are seeing these errors thrown every so often and the service does not work for these users:

```
25-Sep-2017 16:09:38.830 SEVERE [http-nio2-8444-exec-242] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [PortalServlet] in context with path [/selfserviceportal] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$5.isSatisfiedBy(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Prolog.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceI.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Unknown Source)
at com.good.selfservice.ldap.ActiveDirectory.searchInDistinguishedName(ActiveDirectory.java:121)
at com.good.selfservice.ldap.ActiveDirectory.searchContextInDistinguishedName(ActiveDirectory.java:95)
at com.good.selfservice.ldap.ActiveDirectory.findADGroupOfObject(ActiveDirectory.java:235)
at com.good.selfservice.ldap.ActiveDirectory.findADGroupOfObject(ActiveDirectory.java:262)
```

The java:262 line is repeated many times until it stops and then recovers...

I'm not a developer so could someone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably get a developer to look at it.

Comment: There is something unique about the kinds of users who can't use the service successfully.  Those users are probably in a specific AD Group where the distinguished name of the AD Group contains "illegal characters" or something that makes the "AD Group name matching" REGEX Pattern blow up.  (The REGEX probably contains a "look-behind" written such that the REGEX goes into "infinite recursion" when trying to match the input, and thus "stack overflow" comes a 'callin)

Comment: Thanks - i'll ask our AD team to check on the affected users